# Send VirtualBox Guest traffic to Host's router

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I need to send HTTP traffic from the VirtualBox Host through a router. To do this, I think I have to do the following steps:

- Create a SOCKS proxy using `ssh -D`.
- Configure firefox to use the created proxy.

The question is that I need to use two virtual machines (server and router) + my main computer (Host).

Then I need to be able to send HTTP traffic from the Host through the Router, for this I need to perform these steps:

1. Organize socks-proxies using SSH, option `-D`
2. Configure the Firefox browser to use the received socks proxy; I chose the Firefox browser (I have it in ubuntu).

Please help me realize it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your question to include information about what have you tried so far and where have you encountered problems.

Comment: Furthermore you have asked one very similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1417443/Еrror-sending-http-traffic-from-the-host-through-a-router. It even has been answered by you. What's up with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Еrror sending HTTP traffic from the host through a router](https://superuser.com/questions/1417443/%d0%95rror-sending-http-traffic-from-the-host-through-a-router)

Comment: I'm trying to understand local networks. It's my goal!